# SSH Session Break

Tags: unix, ssh

I have a project in which a master server executes scripts on 4 slaves ( 1 slave=master).

All 4 slaves are called upon parallely using & statements like this:

```
sh /data/lpc/scripts/Remote_Execution/Python0/scrap_data_param.sh Python0 $Python0_ip &
  sh /data/lpc/scripts/Remote_Execution/Python1/scrap_data_param.sh Python1 $Python1_ip &
  sh /data/lpc/scripts/Remote_Execution/Python2/scrap_data_param.sh Python2 $Python2_ip &
  sh /data/lpc/scripts/Remote_Execution/Python3/scrap_data_param.sh Python3 $Python3_ip
```

The script ***scrap_data_param*** makes ssh connection to remote IPs and runs various commands in loop.

The problem that I am facing is that the SSH session completes and iterates over the next loop statement even before completion of a  particular SSH session:

I have attached scrap_data_param.sh for your reference:

```
while read line
do
c="n"
for word in $line
do
if [ "$c" = "n" ]; then
 ssh $python_server_ip -n -p 1754 sh /data/lpc/scripts/remote_scraping.sh $word_match $word
done
ssh $python_server_ip -n -p 1754 sh /data/lpc/scripts/remote_matching.sh $word_match

done <'ssss.txt'
```

SO the loop iterates over the next `ssh $python_server_ip -n -p 1754 sh /data/lpc/scripts/remote_matching.sh $word_match` statement before completion of one statement.

Answer (score 0):

One old school book trick might be to put sleep statement between your consecutive commands with sufficient time.

Say like..

```
while read line
do
c="n"
for word in $line
do
if [ "$c" = "n" ]; then
 ssh $python_server_ip -n -p 1754 sh /data/lpc/scripts/remote_scraping.sh $word_match $word
 sleep 10;
done
ssh $python_server_ip -n -p 1754 sh /data/lpc/scripts/remote_matching.sh $word_match
done <'ssss.txt'
```